# special function for solving triangular systems?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

Up to now I solved (regular) triangular systems always using `\` (= `mldivide`). But this function always first [checks whether the matrix is triangular](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) before using an appropriate solver. A naive checking of the triangularity already has about the same order cost as the solving itself. (but therefore increasing the runtime only by a constant factor, so it should usually not matter that much) I wondered:

Is there a built in solver that you can use if you already know that the matrix is triangular that avoids this check?

Comment: Is your matrix upper triangular or lower triangular?

Comment: @romeric That doesn't really matter, that is just reverting the order of the equations.

Comment: Of course it is just a matter of transposing the linear system, but I would say performance-wise it does matter. There is a reason why `LAPACK` has both the variants (in terms of `TRANS/NOTRANS`), and that is exactly what MATLAB's `linsolve` calls under the hood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `linsolve`, which has options for various matrix types including triangular matrices.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html

I tried by using Mathworks' example, both were too fast to matter. When scaled up to 5000x3000, linsolve was much faster. And also useless, as resulting matrices were rank deficient, and the method produced completely wrong results full of NaN. Ordinary division worked as expected - there were some errors, but most results were 1.

Comment: Great, I somehow overlooked that function, thank you!